# retrieving captcha from web site

Tags: web-scraping

I need to retrieve a picture of captcha from site but the source link of captcha seems not normal from all other tutorials

I tried all the approaches, however i think there is nothing wrong from code side, but problem from side of website's captcha as when i save jpg image of the source lin of image i get a picture that doesnt open.

```
#### Code:
r = session.get(url1)
response = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
imageLocation = response.find("img", {"alt": "Captcha image"})["src"]
captchaUrl = url1 + imageLocation
urlretrieve(captchaUrl,'img.jpg')
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="page">
   <form action="/gate" method="post">
    <img alt="Captcha image" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD//gA7Q1JFQVRPUjogZ2Qtan........amz29hK6kFyNqgHueBTbaEC+MKMNtpAkQB9TyT+gqHVf9RF/13T+dSxf8hXUf+uq/+gCgyfxl/wApvVfzpTE3qv51DRQakpib1X86Tym9V/OozSd6QEhib1X86TyW9V/OozTaYE3kt6r+dHkt6r+dRUnegCXyWz1X86XyW9V/Ooe9LQBL5Leq/nRUVFAH/9ky"/>
    <input autofocus="" name="captcha" type="text"/>
    <input name="captchaData" type="hidden" value="1554139767.64d8ba0c7a9dc0fff1ca1c5e2b622c05.0d0ef2fa1b53692cae5ce0e4481293d6"/>
    <input name="ret" type="hidden" value="/"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Войти"/>
   </form>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Share the code you have tried. Actually there is base64-encoded binary of the image `src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<encoded>"`, you just need to decode it and save the binary as a file.

Comment: thank you very much! I thought that was a link in the source, but it was a base64 encoding.